# Why do I get Gradle configure build error junit5 in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I created clean project with spring boot initializer and I get configure build error. The message I get is: `Could not find org.junit:junit-bom:5.4.0-SNAPSHOT.` but in my gradle file I don't have it. What's wrong with it?

```
    buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}


dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
}
```

Comment: The Junit dependency comes with "spring-boot-starter-test", it may not be available in your spring version. Try to change the spring version or use a latest version and give it a go.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Junit dependency comes with **"spring-boot-starter-test"**, it may not be available in your spring version. Try to change the spring version or use a latest version and give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a development (snapshot) version of Spring Boot that refers to a development (snapshot) version of JUnit 5, but you have not added JUnit's snapshot repository: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/junit/junit-bom/5.4.0-SNAPSHOT/:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}
```

But you'd better use generally available versions.